# I have polymorphic relation in my Laravel Models. How to implement them in Nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Below is the entity structure

Exam -> can have 'Descriptive Questions' or 'Multiple Choice Questions' depends on exam type.

```
 public function questions()
    {
        switch($this->exam_type){
            case '1':
                return $this->hasMany('App\Exams\DescriptiveQuestion');
            case '2':
                return $this->hasMany('App\Exams\MultipleChoiceQuestion');
        }
    }
```

How to implement above relationship in nova?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in your resource

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge([
        // another fields
        $this->questionsFields()
    ]);
}

public function questionsFields()
{
    $fields = [];
    if ($this->exam_type == 1) {
        $fields[] = HasMany('Descriptive Question', 'questions', DescriptiveQuestion::class);
    } else {
        $fields[] = HasMany('Multiple Choice Question', 'questions', MultipleChoiceQuestion::class);
    }

    return $fields;
}
```